# Is Scala pattern matching harmful to object orientation?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Disclaimer: I'm much more experienced in Java than in Scala (which I'm learning).

In Java, I have read several times that switch could be harmful to object orientation, especially when used against types (this kind of problems also led to this: http://www.antiifcampaign.com/).

In Scala, one of the introduction video lessons of Martin Odersky shows how pattern matching is a better alternative to multiple "low-level" `isInstanceOf` checks.

Although, pattern matching catches more flexible patterns than a simple Java switch, I still see the first as a generalization of the latter.

Don't pattern matching and "switch on types" roughly share the same fundamental approach?
Isn't pattern matching just some syntactic sugar hiding lots of `isInstanceOf`/`asInstanceOf`?

If not, how would pattern matching be more flexible (as in: resilient to change) than writing those low level checks ourselves (apart from the error-prone nature of this tedious task)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pattern matching may well be "syntactic sugar", in some senses, but it is a lot more than a code replacement.

a) The `match` construct will enforce completeness on the domain by making sure there are no uncovered cases, unless you specifically indicate that it is only a partial function.

b) The match syntax is much less verbose.

c) The match construct includes guards, predicates that qualify the match.

```
def mergeSort(a: List[Int], b: List[Int]): List[Int] = (a, b) match {
  case (ah :: at, bh :: bt) if ah < bh =>
    ah :: mergeSort(at, b)
  case (ah :: at, bh :: bt) if ah >= bh =>
    bh :: mergeSort(a, bt)
  case (Nil, b) =>
    b
  case (a, Nil) =>
    a
}
```

d) Deconstruction

```
...
case Node(x, Empty, Empty) =>
  x - 52
...
```

The declarative form is much easier to read (given a bit of experience).

Edit: the term "syntactic sugar" is used frequently about Scala. However, type inferencing and "aggressive" type resolution such as is used in pattern matching make for powerful language constructs. As for the original question, pattern matching is independent of object orientation and provides powerful, type safe methods for accessing data that may make the use of classes less of a requirement.

Comment: Well, you could edit the C metaphore. I was not stating an argument but asking a question ;-)

Comment: a) and c) are imo the best points in defense of pattern matching, which indeed does more than code replacement.

Answer (score 6):

If you have n types of nouns with m types of verbs, you have n x m noun-verb combinations to keep track of.

There are two good strategies for managing this complexity.

You can organize your code by nouns (classes), and each class needs to be able to deal with every verb (method). This makes it easy to add new nouns. Of course, when you add a new verb, it's annoying to go through each of your nouns and make sure that it can handle the new verb. This is the object-oriented approach.

You can also organize your code by verbs (functions), and each function needs to be able to deal with every noun (pattern). This makes it easy to add new verbs, Of course, when you add a new noun, it's annoying to go through each of your verbs and make sure that it can handle the new noun. This is the functional approach.

There's nothing clearly better about either approach, and both have been used very successfully. You can run into problems when you try to mix them, though, so generally you want to be very clear about which approach you are using for a given problem.

Comment: I'd also say that pattern matching is also exceptional at dealing with cases when you'd like to use multiple dispatch (instead of the single dispatch used by the Scala/Java/JVM). Compare Scala's pattern matching against [emulating it in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#Java).

Comment: Thanks ggovan, I think I was kinda conflating "object-orientation" with single dispatch. You convinced me pattern matching is the best compromise for languages with only single dispatch.

Comment: For the record, the dichotomy you describe here is called “The Expression Problem.” Much has been said and written about it…

Comment: @Randall Thanks, I knew it had a standard name but couldn't recall it.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, pattern matching is done via extractors. Extractors are themselves objects and only have access to the public API of the object that is being pattern matched against.

Thus, pattern matching does not break object encapsulation.

Theoretically, all conditionals (including pattern matching) can be replaced by polymorphism. See Smalltalk as an example of a language which has no conditionals, no loops, no switches, no control structures of any kind except polymorphic message dispatch. And see Newspeak as an example of a Smalltalk-inspired language which has powerful pattern matching inspired by Scala and F# implemented as a library completely on top of polymorphic message dispatch.

When done this way, pattern matching is as object-oriented as can be.